# Android KitKat Failure delivering result ResultInfo?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I've problem with `onActivityResult` only on `KitKat` devices , when user selected image or any file the application get `force closed`,I checked Crashes & ANRS from google developer console and i found this Error

> STACK TRACES 1.1:Application version Android version 4.3 Y530
>   (hwY530-U00) Device java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume
>   activity {packageName.New_Post}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=2803, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://media/external/images/media/3528 flg=0x1 }} to activity
>   {packageName.New_Post}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3012)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3041)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=2803, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://media/external/images/media/3528 flg=0x1 }} to activity
>   {packageName.New_Post}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3614) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2999)
>   ... 12 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   packageName.New_Post.onActivityResult(New_Post.java:343) at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5442) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3610)

and this is the code :

> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
>   Intent data) {
>
> ```
>   //if Sent from Attachment File Send information Back to It
>   if ( requestCode == Api.UPLOAD_ATTACHMENT )
>   {
>       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
>        {
>            Uri uri         = data.getData();
>
>            ContentValues info = new ContentValues();
>
>            info.put("posthash", posthash);
>            info.put("poststarttime", poststarttime);
>            info.put("t", ShowThread.thread.threadid);
>            info.put("p", p);
>            info.put("editpost", 0);
>            info.put("f", ShowThread.thread.forumid);
>            info.put("perm", ( attcperm != null ) ? attcperm.toString() : "");
>
>            new Attachment_upload( context  , uri , info ,attachments_box);  
>        }
>
>   }
> }
> ```

i don't understand I've `resultCode == RESULT_OK` so if the application has not return the attachment file so why results is OK ?

Answer (score 0):

Your URI is incorrect please try to get absolute path

Comment: i did , `Attachment_upload` class is working with URI and getting the absolute path